# Pandas Series get mean value of multiple intervals

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

With an **unevenly spaced datetime Series** like so:

```
date
2019-02-20 13:00:49.268    41.177929
2019-02-20 13:00:50.275    12.431984
2019-02-20 13:00:51.397    18.042411
2019-02-20 13:00:52.434    13.144179
2019-02-20 13:00:53.542    21.349083
                             ...    
2019-02-20 13:05:55.059    51.763360
2019-02-20 13:05:56.169    58.140644
2019-02-20 13:05:57.279     0.411533
2019-02-20 13:05:58.408    48.404780
2019-02-20 13:05:59.518    14.626680
Name: Values, Length: 285, dtype: float64
```

And with a provided **list of datetime intervals** (no overlapping) formatted like: `[(start1, end1), (start2, end2), ...]`

What would be a short way to get the **mean value** of the **Series** in the **combined intervals**? (any interpolation function can be used here)

I'm a pandas beginner and didn't find anything here or in Pandas docs, sorry if this is a dumb question...

Comment: Can you show the expected output? First couple of results may be?

Comment: What is the format of your start and end values in the tuples?

Comment: @harvpan I don't have any result to show yet but I need to get 1 mean value for the combined intervals (not 1 mean per interval).

Comment: @ALollz my start and end values are regular Python datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define the test source *Series* as:

```
2019-02-20 13:00:49.268    40
2019-02-20 13:00:50.275    30
2019-02-20 13:02:51.397    18
2019-02-20 13:02:52.434    13
2019-02-20 13:05:53.542    21
2019-02-20 13:05:55.059    51
2019-02-20 13:06:56.169    32
2019-02-20 13:06:57.279    38
2019-02-20 13:08:58.408    48
2019-02-20 13:08:59.518    14
Name: Val, dtype: int64
```

and the list of intervals as:

```
intv = [(pd.to_datetime('2019-02-20 13:00'), pd.to_datetime('2019-02-20 13:01')),
        (pd.to_datetime('2019-02-20 13:06'), pd.to_datetime('2019-02-20 13:07'))]
```

A preparatory step is to create an *IntervalIndex*:

```
intvInd = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(intv)
```

Then the mean you want can be computed as:

```
s[[intvInd.contains(v) for v in s.index.values]].mean()
```

**Note**

I tried the above solution using *Pandas* version *0.24.2*.
As *Inspi* noticed, at least in version *0.25* the last instruction
must be changed to:

```
s[[any(intvInd.contains(v)) for v in s.index.values]].mean()
```

Apparently, version *0.24* adds this *any(...)* somewhere "under the hood".
In version *0.25* this behavior does not take place.

Comment: I think there's a little mistake in your answer, from what I can see `IntervalIndex.contains` returns an array of bool (for each interval) instead of just True or False, so the code raises `IndexError: too many indices for array`

Comment: *[intvInd.contains(v) for v in s.index.values]* gives a list of *boolean*.
It indicates whether each index value is contained in *intvInd*.
This is OK, as it is used in fancy indexing of *s*. But to run with no error, index values of *s* must be of *Datatime* type.
Maybe your index is of *string* type?

Comment: my indexes are definitely *datetime*, I changed your last line to `s[[any(intvInd.contains(v)) for v in s.index.values]].mean()` to get only 1 bool value and it works now.

Comment: Maybe you use some older version of software?
I use *python: 3.7.0.final.0* and *pandas: 0.24.2*.

Comment: I'm on Python 3.7 and Pandas 25.0, but using `any(...)` makes total sense to me, because if I got it right we want to use a boolean mask to only choose the values we want in s, and if you don't use `any(...)` then `[intvInd.contains(v) for v in s.index.values]` will give you a 2D array size `rows in s * number of intervals`, and you cannot use that as a mask for a 1D column

Comment: You are right. Using *any()* is a more explicite solution. Apparently in my installation this *any()* is added somewhere "under the hood".

Comment: so I switched to Pandas 0.24.2 to try it and indeed, it only worked without `any(...)` ! it looks like for Pandas version < 0.25 you must not put `any(...)` (even though it makes sense) whereas on Pandas >= 0.25 you __must__ use `any(...)`, maybe you can edit your answer so it's complete about that ?

Answer (score 1):

Assume your time series is indexed by date:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2019-07-01', '2019-07-25', freq='T')
s = pd.Series(np.random.uniform(1, 100, len(dates)), index=dates)
```

Some sample data:

```
2019-07-01 00:00:00    54.851538
2019-07-01 00:01:00    82.493677
2019-07-01 00:02:00    80.589765
2019-07-01 00:03:00    54.973948
2019-07-01 00:04:00    18.216064
```

And your intervals are defined in a data frame:

```
intervals = pd.DataFrame([
    ['2019-07-01', '2019-07-02'],
    ['2019-07-02', '2019-07-10']
], columns=['StartDate', 'EndDate'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Simply apply a function over each row in `intervals`:

```
intervals['value'] = intervals.apply(lambda row: s[(row['StartDate'] <= s.index) & (s.index < row['EndDate'])].mean(), axis=1)
```

`s` here is evenly spaced out but that doesn't change the outcome. The date intervals are open on the right (the `<` sign). You can change that depending on your requirements.

Comment: thanks! I validated Valdi_Bo's answer because it seems a bit simpler to me but your answer is helpful too